# Why is DateTime.TryParse making my number into a Date?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

Extension Method

```
   public static class DBNullExt
    {
        public static string DBNToString(this object value)
        {
            if (value == System.DBNull.Value)
                return null;
            else
            {
                string val = value.ToString();
                DateTime test;

                if (DateTime.TryParse(val, out test))
                    return test.ToShortDateString();
                else
                    return val;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where it's used

```
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        dtf.Date1 = rdr["date1"].DBNToString();
                        dtf.Date2 = rdr["date2"].DBNToString();
                        dtf.Cash = rdr["cash"].DBNToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The value that comes from `rdr["cash"].DBNToString()` is 3685.02. But it keeps converting the data to 3685/2/1. It shouldn't be doing that. And I'm not sure why it's doing that.

Comment: Because it fell through to the `else` and succeeded in trying to parse it!? It did what you asked. If you have a problem with it's way of parsing you need to rethink the use of `TryParse` or the conditions you have preceding this.

Comment: It's guessing you've got a format of `yyyy.MM.`, I suspect. Why are you converting to a string and then parsing anyway? Casting would be a better idea... as would avoiding turning everything into a string in general...

Comment: Your data conversions are pretty wild. I'm not surprised you're seeing such effects. You better not use such generic conversion logic. Your code should *know* what type is expected.

Comment: what happens when you use the debugger and step thru the code.. ? even looking at what you have here `data to 3685/2/1` common sense would tell you that you are doing something incorrectly off the bat that's not even a valid date.. what is the datatype in the database in refards to Date1 and Date2 is it stored as a TimeStamp or int or something else ..? are you familiar with `CASTING` for example `dtf.Date1 = (DateTime)rdr["date1"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class DBNullExt
{
    public static string DBNToString(this object value)
    {
        if (value == System.DBNull.Value)
            return null;
        else
        {
            string val = value.ToString();
            DateTime test;

            string format = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(val, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out test))
                return test.ToShortDateString();
            else
                return val;
        }
    }
}
```

As a string, `3685.02` or `2014.10` is an allowable DateTime format. The code above only parses DateTimes in string form that follows the specified format.